# Scanning a text file for matching words in a String [ ] in Java

Tags: java, search

I am having an issue trying to create a method that searches a text file for two or more matching words from a String array and then printing out that found sentence with the matching keywords. In some cases if a user enter only one matching keyword the method is suppose to print out the sentence. If the user enters two matching words the sentence with those two matching words is printed.  My issue is returning two or more found matching keywords. So far I could only search the text file with only one keyword. So, For example, If my text file contains " the ground level is next to the door on your left" and "the ground is beneath here". Then the user enters "ground door", the sentences "the ground level is next to the door on your left" "the ground is beneath here" are returned. My goal is to only return "the ground level is next to the door on your left". My set of matching words are

```
 String [ ] matchwords = {"ground","level","Back", "toll","chair"};
```

And here is my search method which searches the text file.

```
public static void SearchFile(String go) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("bingo.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        final String fileline = scanner.nextLine();
        if (fileline.contains(go)) {
            System.out.println(fileline);

        }

    }
}
```

And in my main method where i call the SearchFile function is here.

```
      public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {
    /* Initialization */

     String [ ] matchwords = {"ground","level","Back", "toll","chair"};


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;

    System.out.println("Welcome To the DataBase ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

        System.out.print("> ");
        input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();


        boolean match = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < matchwords.length && match; i++) {
            //match = input.contains(matchwords[i]);
            if (input.contains(matchwords[i]))  {

                SearchFile(matchwords[i]);
 }
    }

   }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: there is no 'searchFile' method call in main(). Be aware what you copy & paste

Answer (score 0):

```
static String [ ] matchwords = {"ground","level","Back", "toll","chair"};
static List wordList = Arrays.asList(matchwords);

public static void main(String []stg){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = console.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    List line = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
    int noOfWords =0;

    noOfWords = checkWord(line, noOfWords);
    System.out.println("Matched words in a single line : "+noOfWords);
}

public static int checkWord(List list, int counter){
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        if(wordList.contains(list.get(i))){
            list.remove(i);
            checkWord(list, counter);
            counter++;
        }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Question, Where do you open the text file called bingo and search through the file?

Comment: OP's question was not how to open a text file and read, he was struck with determining the number of words.

Comment: Okay I am getting two errors @Jude .. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161). Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I would invert the loop order. Walk the file and on each line look for the appropriate number of matching words. Then print the line as soon as you have enough matches. The way you have this coded, you would have to walk each file once for each potential matched word and then correlate the results to find those lines that would be printed by the minimum number of matches